# Insert at rowid

Tags: javascript, sqlite, titanium

I am struggling to come up with a query for sqlite table to `UPDATE OR INSERT` at rowid. The problem I have is that I have a database where it relies on the rowid but when populating the table there may not be enough rows. So the table may look like this:

```
rowID  data1  data2  data3
------ ------ ----- ------
0      18           1543
1            5
2      35    918
```

And for my query I want to be able to insert `data2 = 453` at rowID = 16 for example. Also just to specify I do not have a column of rowID.

I am thinking that the only way possible would be to insert empty rows from rowID 3 -> 15 before inserting the 16th row. It does not matter for me if rows are empty as they will eventually be populated. I will not be working with more than 50 rows or more than 8 columns so it is a reasonably small table. Anyone know a way forward for me to work?

Also additional thing to note, I am using the query on Titanium, so the programming language is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) says:

> The rowid value can be accessed using one of the special case-independent names "rowid", "oid", or "*rowid*" in place of a column name.
>   [...]
>   An INSERT statement may provide a value to use as the rowid for each row inserted.

So just specify the values you want:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable(rowid, data2) VALUES(16, 453)
```

Comment: Will this work even if there are not the 15 rows before the 16th?